WordPress Dataviews React multilanguage i18n
I'm using React WP dataviews component in my plugin, but I can't load translation for the component.
OFFICIAL DOCS
I loaded plugin translation into php file with:
function umc_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain(
        'unused-media-cleaner',
        false,
        dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages'
    );  
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'umc_load_textdomain' );

and I loaded script js translation into js file with:
wp_set_script_translations( 'umc-script', 'unused-media-cleaner', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages/' );

Plugin translation works fine and also translation inside js file.
But the Dataviews component doesn't load languages.
I don't understand if I am doing something wrong.
I checked default WP domain into /languages/ and it contains string translation.
I checked the same component on site-editor.php page using FSE and it loads translation correctly.

